# Not getting tags after form submit in bootstrap tagsinput java spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using bootstrap tagsinput to show name list into label which are selected from data-table. I am facing one problem is when I submit forms with all search details, selected name list as tags is not showing after forms submit as before tags.Please help me on this.

Comment: Add some code to properly understand the problem.